# lk-sctp sending ABORT while association set-up

Tags: java, netty, rhel5, sctp, rhel6

I am using lksctp-tools-1.0.6-3.el5 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)) on one machine and lksctp-tools-1.0.10-7.el6.x86_64 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)) in another machine.
    I am trying to establish a SCTP association via JAVA application. SCTP server(172.16.150.14) was running on the machine (lksctp-tools-1.0.6-3.el5) and my JAVA SCTP client(172.16.150.69) was creating association through machine (lksctp-tools-1.0.10-7.el6.x86_64). We are getting multiple ABORT while establishment phase itself.
     I am providing the pcap details for reference.

```
No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 05:36:43.098903 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.14         SCTP     82     INIT 

Frame 1: 82 bytes on wire (656 bits), 82 bytes captured (656 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0x00000000
    Checksum: 0xe1257a59 (not verified)
    INIT chunk (Outbound streams: 10, inbound streams: 65535)
        Chunk type: INIT (1)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 36
        Initiate tag: 0xb08220ed
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 131072
        Number of outbound streams: 10
        Number of inbound streams: 65535
        Initial TSN: 3289108916
        Supported address types parameter (Supported types: IPv6, IPv4)
        ECN parameter
        Forward TSN supported parameter

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 05:36:43.099044 172.16.150.14         172.16.150.69         SCTP     250    INIT_ACK 

Frame 2: 250 bytes on wire (2000 bits), 250 bytes captured (2000 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0xb08220ed
    Checksum: 0xb93c0ee7 (not verified)
    INIT_ACK chunk (Outbound streams: 10, inbound streams: 10)
        Chunk type: INIT_ACK (2)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 204
        Initiate tag: 0x4e2a7e3e
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 32768
        Number of outbound streams: 10
        Number of inbound streams: 10
        Initial TSN: 2610537679
        State cookie parameter (Cookie length: 164 bytes)
        ECN parameter
        Forward TSN supported parameter
        Adaptation Layer Indication parameter (Indication: 0)

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 05:36:43.099094 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.14         SCTP     214    COOKIE_ECHO 

Frame 3: 214 bytes on wire (1712 bits), 214 bytes captured (1712 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0x4e2a7e3e
    Checksum: 0x9ed7b037 (not verified)
    COOKIE_ECHO chunk (Cookie length: 164 bytes)
        Chunk type: COOKIE_ECHO (10)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 168
        Cookie: d257bd8304f17a3aaf3d2afa131b81a20000000000000000...

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 05:36:43.099101 172.16.150.14         172.16.150.69         SCTP     60     ABORT 

Frame 4: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0xb08220ed
    Checksum: 0x9a8f1794 (not verified)
    ABORT chunk
        Chunk type: ABORT (6)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x01
        Chunk length: 4

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 05:36:43.099234 172.16.150.14         172.16.150.69         SCTP     60     COOKIE_ACK 

Frame 5: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0xb08220ed
    Checksum: 0x49e57561 (not verified)
    COOKIE_ACK chunk
        Chunk type: COOKIE_ACK (11)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 4

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 05:36:43.115270 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.14         SCTP     74     DATA 

Frame 6: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0x4e2a7e3e
    Checksum: 0xb3dbcc41 (not verified)
    DATA chunk(ordered, complete segment, TSN: 3289108916, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 0, payload length: 11 bytes)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x03
        Chunk length: 27
        TSN: 3289108916
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: not specified (0)
        Chunk padding: 00
Data (11 bytes)

0000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64                  Hello World

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 05:36:43.115369 172.16.150.14         172.16.150.69         SCTP     62     SACK 

Frame 7: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0xb08220ed
    Checksum: 0xe89887f8 (not verified)
    SACK chunk (Cumulative TSN: 3289108916, a_rwnd: 32757, gaps: 0, duplicate TSNs: 0)
        Chunk type: SACK (3)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 16
        Cumulative TSN ACK: 3289108916
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 32757
        Number of gap acknowledgement blocks: 0
        Number of duplicated TSNs: 0

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 05:36:43.115394 172.16.150.14         172.16.150.69         SCTP     60     ABORT 

Frame 8: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0x4e2a7e3e
    Checksum: 0x32aec396 (not verified)
    ABORT chunk
        Chunk type: ABORT (6)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x01
        Chunk length: 4

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 05:36:43.123580 172.16.150.14         172.16.150.69         SCTP     74     DATA 

Frame 9: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0xb08220ed
    Checksum: 0xf927519f (not verified)
    DATA chunk(ordered, complete segment, TSN: 2610537679, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 0, payload length: 11 bytes)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x03
        Chunk length: 27
        TSN: 2610537679
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: not specified (0)
        Chunk padding: 00
Data (11 bytes)

0000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64                  Hello World

No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 05:36:43.123609 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.14         SCTP     50     ABORT 

Frame 10: 50 bytes on wire (400 bits), 50 bytes captured (400 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: Hewlett-_09:e5:c6 (3c:d9:2b:09:e5:c6)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.14 (172.16.150.14)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8080 (8080), Dst Port: 8080 (8080)
    Source port: 8080
    Destination port: 8080
    Verification tag: 0xb08220ed
    Checksum: 0x9a8f1794 (not verified)
    ABORT chunk
        Chunk type: ABORT (6)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x01
        Chunk length: 4
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with same version of lk-sctp : lksctp-tools-1.0.10-7.el6.x86_64 on both my machines. It is working fine for now.

Tested with sctp_test commands:

Please find pcap file for above command as attachment.

```
No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 2014-11-19 07:03:56.983504 172.16.150.73         172.16.150.69         SCTP     82     INIT 

Frame 1: 82 bytes on wire (656 bits), 82 bytes captured (656 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0x00000000
    Checksum: 0xefbed4cf (not verified)
    INIT chunk (Outbound streams: 10, inbound streams: 65535)
        Chunk type: INIT (1)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 36
        Initiate tag: 0x1ae17fe2
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 32768
        Number of outbound streams: 10
        Number of inbound streams: 65535
        Initial TSN: 1274590198
        Supported address types parameter (Supported types: IPv4)
        ECN parameter
        Forward TSN supported parameter

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 2014-11-19 07:03:56.983692 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.73         SCTP     306    INIT_ACK 

Frame 2: 306 bytes on wire (2448 bits), 306 bytes captured (2448 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0x1ae17fe2
    Checksum: 0x27d64e2f (not verified)
    INIT_ACK chunk (Outbound streams: 10, inbound streams: 10)
        Chunk type: INIT_ACK (2)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 260
        Initiate tag: 0xc66950f2
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 131072
        Number of outbound streams: 10
        Number of inbound streams: 10
        Initial TSN: 3426172645
        State cookie parameter (Cookie length: 228 bytes)
        ECN parameter
        Forward TSN supported parameter

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 2014-11-19 07:03:56.983715 172.16.150.73         172.16.150.69         SCTP     298    COOKIE_ECHO DATA 

Frame 3: 298 bytes on wire (2384 bits), 298 bytes captured (2384 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0xc66950f2
    Checksum: 0xa62c78e1 (not verified)
    COOKIE_ECHO chunk (Cookie length: 228 bytes)
        Chunk type: COOKIE_ECHO (10)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 232
        Cookie: 0d369ab0b67060dd9669f00c8536f8830000000000000000...
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590198, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 4060145250, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590198
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (4060145250)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                .

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2014-11-19 07:03:56.983893 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.73         SCTP     66     COOKIE_ACK SACK 

Frame 4: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0x1ae17fe2
    Checksum: 0xda3c636b (not verified)
    COOKIE_ACK chunk
        Chunk type: COOKIE_ACK (11)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 4
    SACK chunk (Cumulative TSN: 1274590198, a_rwnd: 131071, gaps: 0, duplicate TSNs: 0)
        Chunk type: SACK (3)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 16
        Cumulative TSN ACK: 1274590198
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 131071
        Number of gap acknowledgement blocks: 0
        Number of duplicated TSNs: 0

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 2014-11-19 07:03:56.983925 172.16.150.73         172.16.150.69         SCTP     1286   DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA 

Frame 5: 1286 bytes on wire (10288 bits), 1286 bytes captured (10288 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0xc66950f2
    Checksum: 0xeb2aa0d5 (not verified)
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590199, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 1262220821, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590199
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (1262220821)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                .
Stream Control Transmission Protocol
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590200, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 562102819, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590200
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (562102819)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                .
Stream Control Transmission Protocol
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590201, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 1776526345, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590201
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (1776526345)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                .
Stream Control Transmission Protocol
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590202, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 471734626, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590202
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (471734626)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                .
Stream Control Transmission Protocol
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590203, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 328336388, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590203
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (328336388)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                .
Stream Control Transmission Protocol
    DATA chunk(unordered, complete segment, TSN: 1274590204, SID: 0, SSN: 0, PPID: 385618481, payload length: 1 byte)
        Chunk type: DATA (0)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x07
        Chunk length: 17
        TSN: 1274590204
        Stream Identifier: 0x0000
        Stream sequence number: 0
        Payload protocol identifier: Unknown (385618481)
        Chunk padding: 000000
Data (1 byte)

0000  00                                                
No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 2014-11-19 07:03:57.383288 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.73         SCTP     62     SACK 

Frame 8: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0x1ae17fe2
    Checksum: 0xf8ec99a1 (not verified)
    SACK chunk (Cumulative TSN: 1274590297, a_rwnd: 131072, gaps: 0, duplicate TSNs: 0)
        Chunk type: SACK (3)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 16
        Cumulative TSN ACK: 1274590297
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 131072
        Number of gap acknowledgement blocks: 0
        Number of duplicated TSNs: 0

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 2014-11-19 07:03:57.383352 172.16.150.73         172.16.150.69         SCTP     54     SHUTDOWN 

Frame 9: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0xc66950f2
    Checksum: 0xdaccdae0 (not verified)
    SHUTDOWN chunk (Cumulative TSN ack: 3426172644)
        Chunk type: SHUTDOWN (7)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 8
        Cumulative TSN Ack: 3426172644

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 2014-11-19 07:03:57.383479 172.16.150.69         172.16.150.73         SCTP     60     SHUTDOWN_ACK 

Frame 10: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2), Dst: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69), Dst: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0x1ae17fe2
    Checksum: 0x28d88127 (not verified)
    SHUTDOWN_ACK chunk
        Chunk type: SHUTDOWN_ACK (8)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 4

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     11 2014-11-19 07:03:57.383498 172.16.150.73         172.16.150.69         SCTP     50     SHUTDOWN_COMPLETE 

Frame 11: 50 bytes on wire (400 bits), 50 bytes captured (400 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_77:28:14 (ac:16:2d:77:28:14), Dst: Hewlett-_09:fa:f2 (3c:d9:2b:09:fa:f2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.150.73 (172.16.150.73), Dst: 172.16.150.69 (172.16.150.69)
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 8887 (8887), Dst Port: 8887 (8887)
    Source port: 8887
    Destination port: 8887
    Verification tag: 0xc66950f2
    Checksum: 0xcb7bef01 (not verified)
    SHUTDOWN_COMPLETE chunk
        Chunk type: SHUTDOWN_COMPLETE (14)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 4
```

Just one doubt, whether this will work seamlessly with other SCTP stack too?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I just ran across this problem after spending a few hours wondering what had gone wrong with an SCTP server and client that had worked the day before.

After doing some reading, I had added

```
net.sctp.addip_enable = 1
```

to /etc/sysctl.conf - after noticing that option was available, and figuring that adding and removing IP addresses to/from an association after it had been created would be a useful thing.  It appears to simply break SCTP, or require alterations to how you create the connection.  That produced the exact behavior described above.

Commenting out the line and rebooting restored SCTP to working order.